# How to use my simple custom django template tag with if statement?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am trying to use my simple tag with if in django template.As far as i know assignment tag is removed from Django 2.0 . My template tag is:-

```
@register.simple_tag
def channelpostlike(postid,userid):
  print(userid)
  postresult=ChannelPost.objects.get(id=postid)
  if postresult.user_like.filter(id=userid).exists():
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

I want to use it like:-

```
{%if channelpostlike c.id request.user.id %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs:

> assignment_tag Deprecated since version 1.9 simple_tag can now store results in a template variable and should be used instead.

So you can use `simple_tag` like this:

```
# You can access the result as something anywhere you like
{% channelpostlike c.id request.user.id as something %}
{% if something %}
    <p>Something ...</p>
{% endif %}
```